# Want to get a matrix inverse without using solve function

Tags: r, matrix

I want to find the value of inversed matrix without using a function `solve(x)`.

```
inversed matrix = 1/det(x)  *  "cofactor"^(transpose)
```

I know that a determinant of matrix = `det(x)` and a transpose of matrix = `t(x)`. But I cannot find out how to get cofactor of matrix x and get inversed matrix.

Comment: I am curious to know the reason...why not use `solve`?

Answer (score 4):

The (i,j)th minor of a matrix is that matrix with the ith row and the jth column removed.

```
minor <- function(A, i, j)
{
  A[-i, -j]  
}
```

The (i,j)th cofactor is the (i,j)th minor times -1 to the power i + j.

```
cofactor <- function(A, i, j)
{
  -1 ^ (i + j) * minor(A, i, j)
}
```

A word of warning: you shouldn't use this method of calculating inverses of matrices, except for homework purposes, because it is computationally intensive, and (if I recall correctly) not very numerically stable.  For real-world purposes use `solve` or `qr.solve` or `chol2inv`.  Compare these:

```
A <- matrix(c(5,1,1,3),2,2)
solve(A)
qr.solve(A)
chol2inv(chol(A))
```

Comment: @hd1: That's why I started with a non-`solve` solution.  For anyone else reading this afterwards, it's important to note that inverting a matrix in R the same way you would using pen and paper is silly.  This is why I also provided the best R-like solutions, which include the use of the `solve` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a precomputed cholesky decomposition, `chol2inv` will sort you.